# Google Maps Geocoding API - Request Denied using API Key

Tags: google-places-api

I'm trying to use the Google API geocode service as follows:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=melbourne&key=xxx&sensor=false
```

The response I get is always:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I have both Google maps API v3 and Places API services enabled.  I have even set up billing.  I have tried deleting and recreating numerous keys - all with the same effect.  I have tried the service from different networks, also with the same result.

In the reports section of the Google API dashboard I can see the number of request accumulating but the response is always `Request_Denied`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Lose the `key`. It works without it: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=melbourne&sensor=false

Comment: Yeah, I know...but the requests are limited to 1000 a day and I need more than that.  The key is meant to grant 25000 requests a day and then paid requests after that.....need to get the key working.

Comment: Turns out, this API is only available to [Maps API for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices) customers. Have you had a look at our [Geocoding library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) in Google Maps Javascript v3?

Comment: Re-checked that Geolocation API is also enabled. Same response.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The REQUEST_DENIED status is [returned by the Places API when](https://developers.google.com/places/faq#why_do_i_keep_receiving_status_request_denied):

- You have not activated the Places API Service in the services tab of the APIs console.
- The key parameter is missing from your request.
- The key parameter does not match the your API key in the API Access tab of the APIs console.
- Your API key has not been correctly set up in the API Access tab of the APIs Console:
- If you are using a Browser key, check that your allowed Referer(s) are correct.
- If you are using a Server key, check that your allowed IP(s) are correct.
- Android and iOS keys are not supported, please use a Browser or Server key.
- The request was not sent as an HTTPS request, HTTPS is required for all Web Service requests.
- The incorrect HTTP method was used to send the request:
- All requests must be sent as a GET request except for Place Actions.
- All Place Actions must be sent as a POST request.

I failed to whitelist my production server's IP address.

Comment: If the Android and iOS keys are not supported, why allow us to create them in the first place!?!?!?!?

Comment: @MarcoLuglio because some other Google APIs do allow these type of keys (e.g. Google Cloud Vision API). But I do agree it is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems intentional that the key doesn't work with simple HTTP queries for Geocoding. Google is preventing any possible repurposing of the data. See the ["Usage Limits"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits):

> "The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map;
>   geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited."

You can load the results on a map using the Javascript API as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder).

Answer (score 0):

Only change the googleapis source like this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
```